# Lazy load not working after Ajax call to fetch same data again

Tags: jquery, ajax, lazy-loading

I have this ajax call, and it returns the right data, but lazy loading stops working, the images load immediately which leads to a big delay (hence the desire for lazy load). Lazy load works fine with PHP written data without using Ajax, but after the Ajax data is returned, no more lazy load.

```
        $.ajax({
                url:"/images-ajax.php",
                cache:false,
                data:"s="+selection,
                method:"post",
                success:function(html){
                        $(".masonryImg").html(html);
                        $("div.curve4 li").removeClass("selected");
                        that.addClass("selected");
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                        console.log(thrownError);
                  }
        });
```

The ajax call overwrites the content of .masonryImg div, but initially I only have in each image " data-src='".$imageLocation.$fileOnly.".jpg'", but with Ajax code being generated I must include 'src=....' or no data shows.
Which could mean that I should not use src=, just data-src= and get lazy load to work somehow?

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have spent hours on this topic and days, I know someone will come with little help or lot... I have many pictures to show on any given page, so showing a screenful only and then more after a user scrolls is ideal - hence Lazy Load. Then ajax calls to get another page, and I want to get Lazy Load on that returned data...................... I am eagerly awaiting someone's input.

Comment: if it's just PHP, it would populate the .masonryImg div, and lazy load works. Now when Ajax is called to replace the content of that div, right away images start showing. How can my Ajax be resolved so that the new data can also be showing using Lazy Load. Lazy Load code is included in <head> section of the php file with JS and CSS components.